# Will "Install Alongside Windows" use the empty space I create?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

before I install UIbuntu on my main system along side windows I'd like to get some confirmation on what the installer will do when "install alongside windows" is chosen.

Here are what drives and partitions I have.

SSD (128gb) - Used entirely by Windows 10.

SSD (500GB) - NTFS partition at 400GB, the other 100gb is empty, this is where I want Ubuntu to install itself.

HDD (2TB) - NTFS storage drive, one partition for the whole drive.

If I choose the "install alongside windows" option will it find that empty space and use it or will I have to do it manually? If I have to do it manually could you tell me what partitions to make.

Thank you.

Comment: No. There is no way the installer knows your intentions. "Install alongside..." option usually shrinks the Windows partition, and then installs Ubuntu. In your case, use the "Something else..." options, and create partitions manually.

Comment: Reading the installation guide it says " If you have more than 2 HDD pay attention to where the bootloader is going to be installed since it could potentially mess your install", where should I make sure the bootloader goes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "*install alongside...*" option. Use the "*something else*" option. You need to create at least one partition, namely the root, denoted by "`/`". Set aside 35GB. I'd also install a "`/home`" partition,  which is optional, and maybe set aside 25GB. Both these 2 partititions should be formatted as ext4. You can create a "`swap area`", but it's also optional, unless you intend to use your computer in a way that will be heavy on memory. I wouldn't use more than 8GB for that.

There's also a "`/boot`" partition needed, but Ubuntu creates that one automatically. It should take care of creating and placing your bootloader. That takes up about 100MB and is shared between Windows and Ubuntu.

Have a good read of [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) before you do anything then you shouldn't go wrong.